# State machine transition timing calculation using c++

Tags: c++11, state-machine

I was written state machine implementation using C++ code , Now i need calculate the transition timing between one system state to another system state ? Please help any API is there in C++ to calculate timing between the states ?

Please suggest ideas any other way to calculate state transition timing ?
Ex:

System is in ON state --> System is OFF state { timing between on to Off and Graph }

Example:systemd-analyze to create timing graph based process spwaned

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Measuring execution time of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/c-measuring-execution-time-of-a-function)

Answer (score -1):

first use ntp server Synchronize different system,second use timestamp flag state. collect state and calculate .