# C++ - Performance of static arrays, with variable size at launch

Tags: c++, arrays, performance-testing, dynamic-memory-allocation, cellular-automata

I wrote a cellular automaton program that stores data in a matrix (an array of arrays). For a 300*200 matrix I can achieve 60 or more iterations per second using static memory allocation (e.g. `std::array`).

I would like to produce matrices of different sizes without recompiling the program every time, i.e. the user enters a size and then the simulation for that matrix size begins. However, if I use dynamic memory allocation, (e.g. `std::vector`), the simulation drops to ~2 iterations per second. How can I solve this problem? One option I've resorted to is to pre-allocate a static array larger than what I anticipate the user will select (e.g. 2000*2000), but this seems wasteful and still limits user choice to some degree.

I'm wondering if I can either

a) allocate memory once and then somehow "freeze" it for ordinary static array performance?

b) or perform more efficient operations on the `std::vector`? For reference, I am only performing `matrix[x][y] == 1` and `matrix[x][y] = 1` operations on the matrix.

According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap), there is no difference in performance between `std::vector` or using pointers.

EDIT:

I've rewritten the matrix, as per UmNyobe' suggestion, to be a single array, accessed via `matrix[y*size_x + x]`. Using dynamic memory allocation (sized once at launch), I double the performance to 5 iterations per second.

As per PaulMcKenzie's comment, I compiled a release build and got the performance I was looking for (60 or more iterations per second). However, this is the foundation for more, so I still want to quantify the benefit of one method over the other more thoroughly, so I used a [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c) to time each iteration, and found that the performance difference between dynamic and static arrays (after using a single array matrix representation) to be within the margin of error (450~600 microseconds per iteration).

The performance during debugging is a slight concern however, so I think I'll keep both, and switch to a static array when debugging.

Comment: It seems that those differences in performance are related to compiler optimisations (did you turn them on?). Please provide your code if you require precise answer.

Comment: Are you using a std::vector<std::vector<something>>?

Comment: Have you tried *constructing* the vector with a [starting size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)?  You should read up on some of the constructors.

Comment: For high performance, your rows should be able to fit inside your processor's data cache line.  More than one row per cache line also works.

Comment: std::vector of std::vector has poor locality as the data is not contiguous, leading to a higher likelihood of cache misses versus the contiguous std::array. You might want to consider forcing contiguity by using a 1D std::vector and performing the indexing (row * num_columns + column) yourself. The extra math is comparable to what is done behind the scenes so you lose nothing. std::vector will also initialize its contents, but that should count for at most a few percent in lost performance. good hints here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: @OP: You did not indicate whether you're timing with optimizations turned on.  If you're timing an unoptimized build, you're wasting your time with these observations.  You should be timing optimized builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For reference, I am only performing

```
matrix[x][y]
```

- **Red flag!** Are you using `vector<vector<int>>`for your matrix
  representation? This is a mistake, as rows of your matrix will be far
  apart in memory. You should use a single vector of size `rows x cols`
  and use `matrix[y * row + x]`
- Furthermore, you should follow the approach where you index first by rows and then by columns, ie `matrix[y][x]` rather than `matrix[x][y]`. Your algorithm should also process the same way. This is due to the fact that with `matrix[y][x]` (x, y) and (x + 1, y) are one memory block from each other while with any other mechanism elements `(x,y)` and `(x + 1, y)`, `(x, y + 1)` are much farther away.

Even if there is performance decrease from std::array to std::vector (as the array can have its elements on the stack, which is faster), a decent algorithm will perform on the same magnitude using both collections.