# Calculating the running time of a program in seconds in c++

Tags: c++, runtime, codeblocks

I am new to programming. I have written a small program in C++ and want to calculate the running time of the program in seconds so that I can plot a graph for input size versus running time. But how will I get the exact running time? When I run the program using Code Blocks, does the result of execution time is the running time of the program or is there any other way to get it?

Comment: In Unix-land you can just use the `time` command, if the processing time of the program overwhelms its startup and termination time. Otherwise the `<chrono>` header provides clocks you can use to build a timer used within the code. I.e., *instrumenting* the code. The simplest timer is to use old `clock`. But it has low resolution in Windows.

Comment: Can you include `time.h` in your program?

Comment: Yes, it's the running time. But you may not want to use it since it contains start up and other times.

Comment: then how will I get the exact running time? @apple apple

Comment: This may be what you looking for: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14666/

Comment: since you use c++, I would recommend use <ctime> instead of <time.h> (almost the same)

Comment: or if you have c++11 and knows template, maybe try <chrono>

Comment: @appleapple why do you say that, is <ctime> specify made for c++?

Comment: @appleapple: `<ctime>` yields less portable code than `<time.h>`. It has no advantage that I know. In the first standard, C++98, these headers were invented in order to place identifiers in namespace `std` only, avoiding pollution of the global namespace, but no compiler vendors adhered to that spec. It was changed in C++11. So the original purpose is gone, and there was nothing more.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf How is it less portable?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Usually people use an unqualified identifier such as `clock`. That's what one's used to from C code. Compile with some other compiler and that identifier is not available in the global namespace.

Comment: That is not less portable.  If you are using <c****> then you need to use `std::`. Using the header wrong is not a lack of portability,

Comment: @NathanOliver: A header that makes the code less likely to be portable, allowing mistakes to be not caught with some compilers, yields, well you know, code that is less portable. One may deny that that's lack of portability, of course.

Comment: Well, one may also find std::clock cannot us in some compiler when they include  <time.h>

Comment: I do not buy that.  If the header puts everything in the standard namespace (which is guaranteed) then you should use it as such.

Comment: @NathanOliver do you reply to my comment or Cheers?

Comment: Well, the facts are that this happens. So, essentially, your authority source, whatever or whoever that is, is wrong. It's just dumb to invite problems.

Comment: @appleapple No it was to the one above.  Your got in right when I pressed enter.

Comment: The `<c...>` headers are more portable because they are the only ones that guarantee `std::` prefix. The `.h` headers may or may not making them less portable for `C++` code and more likely to clash with other libraries in a way that can't easily be disambiguated.

Comment: What problem are you inviting @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you use `<c***>` and `std::name_from_header` there is no problem and you have portable code.  Not only is there no problem but now the names are scoped so it can cut down on name conflicts.

Comment: If you are after the performance of particular piece of code (for performance tuning), you should rather look for some "profiler" solution, timing each interesting code block by hand is a bit tedious, and you may miss some bottleneck in a part of code, which you don't want to measure, as it looks uninteresting.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If you do everything just right there is no problem, agreed. There is no need for type checking either. Just do things right.

Comment: You can refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40380118/6180077 . program shows how to calculate time difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [Boost Cpu Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html), note auto_cpu_timer's destructor prints result.

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
  // you're stuff here

return 0;
};
```