# Same code executed twice : performance difference

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why the same piece of code, executed twice, seems to be executed faster the first time than the second time?

I tried the code bellow about 20 times, every time the first execution was faster than the second one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

void add(int* var) {(*var)++;}

int main()
{
    int var = 0;
    clock_t tStart;

    tStart = clock();
    for(int i=450000000;i--;) {add(&var);}
    printf("%.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    tStart = clock();
    for(int i=450000000;i--;) {add(&var);}
    printf("%.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

It is really tiny, but still why is there a difference?

```
1.28s
1.36s
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Would I have done something wrong? Maybe has it something to do with how I am timing the thing rather than with the speed of execution?

Thanks

Comment: OS is throttling your program?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Is this repeatable? On my system over a large number of runs the times are equal (1.05 sec +/- 0.03 sec or so), with gcc 5.4.1 on Linux/x64 with `-O3`. Due to process scheduling and system load there will always be some random variation.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of a lot of evil.
Is there a particular performance issue you are encountering in regards to doing 450000000 printf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested int the comments bellow the question, turning the optimization off solved the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There could be a million reasons why the speed of the execution was slightly different. It could have ran at the same time the system was doing some maintenance, the system could have outsourced the same thread to other processes, etc.

Also, using `clock()` to measure for performance is not accurate, as it does not really measure time, but rather CPU cycles. I would recommend using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. An example of usage [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387757/8772958).

Comment: If I'm measuring performance, I'm usually more interested in CPU cycles than wall time, so your second paragraph doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @TypeIA It depends what kind of profiling you are doing, I just assumed Baristophon was interested in the execution time based off his question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what services are running each second by your CPU or what threads are being processed on each run of your code .. think of it as stateless environment variables on each run .