# Faster way to create a sorted copy of a vector

Tags: algorithm, sorting, vector

Given an unsorted vector as source, the goal is to create a sorted copy as fast as possible.
There are two possibilities:
1. create a vector copy then sort it
2. or insert each element one after the other, to build the sorted vector incrementally.

Which is theoretically the faster way?

Comment: Insertion sort is N^2, so probably will be faster to use merge sort or some NLOGN sort .

Comment: What you describe with 1. is an "in-place" algorithm. It has nothing to do with faster or not. This is more a problem of memory consumption, than of speed. Every sort algorithm depends on your input vector. Just use the std::sort and you will be fine. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: `std::sort()` has complex `O(N log N)`.   Insertion sort (second approach) has complexity `O(N*N)`.     If the number of elements is significant, the first option wins on performance.   For a small number of elements, YMMV.

Comment: If those are your only two options (1) is your best worst-case, especially when using something like `std::sort`. And since you're on the subject of "theoretical", if the underlying range of data is sufficiently range-restricted (say integers in 1...100 exclusively), it can be done with something like counting-sort in O(n), which is basically unbeatable in the sorting world. Not that it matters much, since it isn't one of your two options.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, why did anyone downvote it?

Comment: @JohnZ.Li This is not a legitimate question. Its school homework .

Comment: @sagi it boils down to the following: can sort algorithms be made faster if one has some extra memory as large as the data set.

Answer (score 1):

This question has very little to do with C++ specifically (except using the word "vector", which also exists in may other languages). Since this reads like an exercise, I really recommend writing a program to test it out:

```
1. write a program that builds a vector of random N integers, v1
2. copy the vector to v2, via std::copy
3. time how long it takes to use insertion-sort (option 2 above), using a loop
4. time how long std::sort(v2, v2.begin(), v2.end()) takes
```

You can time things using different timers, either the old `<ctime>` header or the newer `<chrono>` one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c) for alternatives.

You should find that, for small sizes of N, the loop from step 3 is faster or equivalent to step 4 - and from a few hundred onward, `std::sort` becomes better and better. Welcome to asymptotic complexity and [big-o notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation)!

Answer (score 0):

Answers can be found in the following nice conference: in short, this depends on the size of the vector. Hence Peter's comment is the best one.
[CppCon 2018: Frederic Tingaud “A Little Order: Delving into the STL sorting algorithms”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0tO3Eni2uo)