# is std::copy faster than std::cout for output?

Tags: c++, buffer

```
std::vector<int> v{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

// print the numbers
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
```

here std::copy is used to write to std out. Is this faster than using std::cout for the vector elements in a for loop like

```
for(auto element: v) std::cout << element << " ";
```

I could't find much information about how they would write to output buffers for both.

Comment: Did you try to profile it before ? I think you can easily find the answer by yourself :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I need to know if they work differently; if so, how?

Comment: You could look at the created assembler code, if you want to know, how they work

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c show how you can measure it

Comment: Pretty sure the bottle neck will be the console itself anyway, so if there are differences, they most likely are neglectable...

Answer (score 2):

To give an rough idea on the relative performance of the two, see the benchmark results here: http://quick-bench.com/wGYYPBXEgvLrkyp5gpJOnIpt7A4

I had to output to a `std::stringstream` instead of `std::cout` to keep quick-bench happy. It gives some insight on the raw performance of the underlying implementations, but not on how they crossplay with a highly OS dependent output stream like `std::cout`.

So it is hard to come to any definitive conclusions based on such a simple benchmark alone. I would take from this that in reality there is most likely not enough difference between the two approaches to prefer one over the other from a performance perspective.