# C++ clock() function time.h returns unstable values

Tags: c++, time, clock, execution

I need to measure time for certain code block execution for research and a framework.
I have tried **clock()** and **time()** from **time.h**, both returns 0. I have no idea why the distance of clocks either becomes zero. But, **QueryPerformanceCounter** from **windows.h** library returns a reliable answer but not works in Linux. They'd used **Large_Integer** data type. What would be a lightweight way to measure time in frameworks for evaluations? It means I am looking for a gain of execution time so hate overheads.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measuring execution time of a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c)

Comment: How can we possibly comment on what you are doing right or wrong when you don't show us your code?