# C++ Using Time as variable to store event length to reproduce later

Tags: c++, time.h

Long story short:

I am trying to measure the time difference between the start & end of an event (a device executing a command), because I want to reproduce that later on as a return Home command.

But, it seems that for the same event, the time is way different, it varies by a factor of x2.

Here is my testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  clock_t t;
  t = clock();
  for(int i =0; i < 50; i++) { cout << i << " ";}
  t = clock() - t;
  printf ("\nIt took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n", t, ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know anything better to get better results?

***Context:***
Sending commands to a device via BlueTooth, like rotating both motors at X speed while the <kbd>VK_UP</kbd> key is pressed, and stopping motors when <kbd>VK_UP</kbd> is released. The idea is to map all these commands using execution time between keypressed-keyreleased and later on to build a Return Home function.

Comment: 1) Sample size of 50 is probably too small. 2) IO operations are wildly inconsistent in timing, so, for code you posted, a lot of variation is expected.

Comment: I cannot give a bigger size because my target event may be very short, key pressed - key released. I need something sensitive

Comment: The for loop up to 50 with cout inside is absolutely no way to get a constant real time duration for testing time measurement. You are lucky, if it varies only by x2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, consider measure time using C++ facilities like in this question:

[Measuring execution time of a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22387586/1593077)

Then, the execution time of a piece of code may be impacted by many circumstances, so you should treat it like a random variable of sorts, and measure it multiple times, or measure the sum of times and divide by the number of repetitions.

Finally, your computer is not spending all of its time just executing your program; so - you may want to use something like `time` program, or a profiler application, to figure out how much processor time your program actually got.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is what I need. 
For example, in my case, I send a command to a device via bluetooth, like rotate both motors at X speed while I press VK_UP and stop motors when VK_UP gets released. The idea is to map all those commands using execution time between keypressed-keyreleased and later on to build a Return Home function