# Dynamic Fibonacci program

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, greedy

Not entirely sure if I implemented it correctly, but I tried to use memoization for this fib programme and it turns out to be slower than if I just ran it without,
does anyone know why this is happening?

~Finding the 39th value  in the sequence.

*Results without Map (Memoization):
39
63245986
Time taken by program is : 1.000000  sec

*Results with Map:
39
63245986
Time taken by program is : 35.000000  sec

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int fibNum(int n) {

    map <int, int> mp = {};

    if(mp.find(n) != mp.end()){
        return mp[n];
    } else 
/* Remove this top part for non-map way*/

    if (n == 1 || n == 2){
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        int answer = fibNum(n - 1) + fibNum(n - 2);
        mp[n] = answer; 
/* Remove this part about assigning value to the key*/
        return answer;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*Running the Fibonnac Programme, main programme is above*/

int main() {
    int term; cin >> term;
    
    time_t start,end;
    time(&start);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 

    cout << fibNum(term) << endl;

    time(&end);

    double timeTaken = double(end - start);
    cout << "Time taken by program is : " << fixed 
        << timeTaken << ' ' << " sec\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change your mp to `static map<int,int>` so you can reuse the instance on every call made to fibNum. Also just change your implementation to a non-recursive one (it can still use memoization by storing previous results in the map)

Comment: Another thing map will have a lot of machinery going on too for each call to find.  So if you use a std::vector you can see by its length how many numbers you already stored. 
Also forget about `sync_with_stdio` it is usually not needed at all (and mostly used in competitive coding only)

Comment: To use memoization  the map must be created only once. Your map is recreated every time that you call `fibNum`, so it adds nothing but overhead to your program.

Comment: I guess you are thinking that because your function is recursive that the map is preserved between recursive calls. If this is what you are thinking then you are falling into a common trap, remember there is *nothing special about recursive functions*. Recursive functions follow **exactly** the same rules as any other function.

Comment: Your basic mistake are using associative container (`std::map`) and not making it `static`. Use `std::vector` and make it `static`.

Comment: Besides what has already been mentioned above, you might notice better performance by using `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`. The run-time complexity of `std::unordered_map` is better than `std::map`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
After some more time spent on the topic and the discovery (at least for me) of some of the beauty behind the Fibonacci sequence and its associated algorithm, I published my definitive guide at [this address](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint/blob/dev/fibonacci.md).

My initial answer, below, is still valid but what the library I posted in the same repository brings is:

- The code is cleaner and easier to understand, with an actual matrix type.
- Performance was improved: all Fibonacci numbers between index 50000 an index 55000 are calculated in 20-25ms (printing of numbers excluded as I had not measured that back then).
- The matrix exponantiation algorithm no longer needs to start at Fibonacci(1): if you give the algorithm 2 consecutive Fibonacci numbers (or `n` consecutive numbers for generalized sequences), it can calculate any subsequent number (for instance, you could save some numbers into a file/database as text so that the next time you run your program, you can restart from there).
  I think that last point truly removes all the benefits from implementing a cache.

---

There are several options to optimize the calculation of the fibonacci sequence:

1. Reuse known values.
2. During the calculation of `fibonacci(n)`, avoid a recursion where `2^n` branches extend to `fibonacci(1)`.
3. Return ranges of values instead of individual values.

Memoization lets you achieve point 1 and because it does, it also lets you achieve point 2. This comes at a cost though, and I will detail what I mean by that later in my answer.

What I would like to explore for now is a solution that achieves points 2 and 3.

### Step 0: Some prerequisites

You can only store up to `fibonacci(93)` using 64-bit integers. To overcome that limitation, I have used the bigint library provided at [this address](https://github.com/rgroshanrg/bigint). Likely not the best thing out there but easy enough to use; I am sure other bigint libraries would work too.

For ease of use later, we will use 2 constants, which are going to be the bounds of the range we want to calculate:

```
#define MININDEX 1000
#define MAXINDEX 1500
```

### Step 1: calculate fibonacci values in linear complexity

What is important to understand with the fibonacci sequence is that you only need to remember the last 2 terms to calculate the next one. Put a different way, every term is useful immediately after being calculated and then **only once more**.
Whe can use that fact to create a simplified non-recursive function.

```cpp
bigint fibonacci(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    bigint  a = 1, b = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        bigint  c = a;
        a = a + b;
        b = c;
    }
    return a;
}
```

For the record, I did not consider returning several values in my original answer so this function was what I submitted.

Ignoring the fact that arithmetic operations, and intialization/copy operations have non constant complexity for very big numbers, the above function executes in `O(n)` operations unlike the classic approach (`fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`) or your attempt using a `std::map` (looking `n` times into a map is `O(n log(n)`).

It is easy to understand how `O(n)` is the best complexity we can hope for when calculating all the consecutive `fibonacci(i)` values: we cannot get `n` results in less than `n` operations.
With that said, this version of the function to get all `fibonacci(i)` values between `n1` and `n2` still is at `O((n2 - n1)^2)` complexity.

### Step 2: Filling a vector with consecutive values

To avoid having to restart the calculation from 1 for every consecutive values, the above function can easily be changed to return a vector with all the consecutive values between 2 indices.
The vector in that version is the out parameter `result`:

```cpp
void fibonacci_range(std::vector<bigint>& result, unsigned short from, unsigned short to) {
    auto [a, b] = some_magical_function(from); //We need consecutive 2 values to start the loop.
    result.push_back(a);

    for (unsigned short i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        bigint c = a;
        a += b;
        bigint::_big_swap(b, c);
        result.push_back(std::move(a));
    }
}
```

### Step 3: Calculating the values at the start of the returned sequence

As you may have noticed, the above function uses a call to `some_magical_function(from)`, not yet defined. We could tweak the previous `fibonacci` function to return 2 values and call it here.

However, in the case where you need only 2 consecutive values rather than all consecutive values within a range, the `O(n)` algorithm is not the best one.
As was explained in another answer (and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form)), there exists an algorithm that can calculate `fibonacci(n)` while skipping most values between 1 and `n` along the way, thus achieving a `O(log(n))` complexity.

TBH, I would have upvoted the other answer, had the code been better optimized. Rather than using it, I have written a faster version to make it more practical.

One of the trick is to store 2x2 symmetrical matrices as 3 elements in an array.

```cpp
#include <array>
void matrix_power(std::array<bigint, 3>& result, std::array<bigint, 3>& M, unsigned int exp) {
    auto multiplyWith = [] (std::array<bigint, 3>&target, const std::array<bigint, 3>& with)
    {
        bigint a = target[0] * with[0] + target[1] * with[1],
               b = target[0] * with[1] + target[1] * with[2],
               c = target[1] * with[1] + target[2] * with[2];
        target[0] = std::move(a);
        target[1] = std::move(b);
        target[2] = std::move(c);
    };
    while (exp > 1) {
        if ((exp & 1) == 1)
            multiplyWith(result, M);
        multiplyWith(M, M);
        exp = exp >> 1;
    }
    multiplyWith(result, M);
}

std::pair<bigint,bigint> fibonacci_matrix(unsigned int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return std::make_pair(0, static_cast<int>(n));

    //As an optimization, 2x2 symmetric matrices are stored as 3 numbers.
    std::array<bigint, 3> fiboMatrix    = { 1, 1, 0 },
                          result_matrix = { 1, 0, 1 };

    matrix_power(result_matrix, fiboMatrix, n - 1);
    return std::make_pair(result_matrix[0], result_matrix[1]);
}
```

### Step 4: combine both functions

In the definition of `fibonacci_range(...)` all you have to do is replace `some_magical_function` by `auto [a, b] = fibonacci_matrix(from);`

When calculating all the values between `n1` and `n2`, the complexity becomes `O(log(n1)) + O(n2 - n1)`.

You could achieve that same complexity with only a modified version of `fibonacci_matrix` but 2x2 matrix multiplication uses a little bit more arithmetic operations than what the `fibonacci_range` does for each term, hence such solution would be a little bit slower.

---

### Complete code

I have created an example to test different versions of the fibonacci function, without a cache and with different versions of a cache (`map` as in your question + unordered_map as was suggested in a comment + C-style array just to see what the fastest container I can think of can do).

Every cached version runs twice. The first time, it runs from an empty cache while the second time, the cache is first initialized with the first value of the returned range, then calculates the rest from there.
For ranges beyond 20k I recommend you only keep the versions with no cache or for which the cache is initialized **separately** (meaning you should disable the calls that are done on an empty cache).

In the scenario I coded, the function without a cache is always faster (sometimes by a long shot), which means you are using memory (potentially a lot of it if you store many very large integers) to make your algorithm slightly slower.
**It should be obvious BTW**: values stored in cache are never used more than twice. Just the 2 variables of the "vanilla" algorithm are enough.
This was my initial point: having a cache does not necessarily means that you are using it and that it will save you any time. Going beyond what 64-bit integers can do, how long does it even take to copy values in and out of the cache?

The (almost) final result on my computer is all the values between `fibonacci(50000)` and `fibonacci(55000)` are returned in 10 to 12 secs, faster than any cache can give me.

Full code:

```cpp
#include <bigint.h>

#define MININDEX 50000
#define MAXINDEX 55000


bigint fibonacci(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    bigint  a = 1, b = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        bigint  c = a;
        a = a + b;
        b = c;
    }
    return a;
}


bigint fiboArrayCache[1 + MAXINDEX] = { 0, 1 };
unsigned int fiboCalcUntil_array = 1;

bigint fibonacci_array(unsigned int n) {
    if (n <= fiboCalcUntil_array)
        return fiboArrayCache[n];


    bigint a = fiboArrayCache[fiboCalcUntil_array], b = fiboArrayCache[fiboCalcUntil_array - 1];

    for (unsigned int i = fiboCalcUntil_array; i < n; ++i) {
        bigint c = a;
        a = a + b;
        b = c;
        fiboArrayCache[1 + i] = a;
    }
    fiboCalcUntil_array = n;
    return a;
}


#include <map>
std::map<unsigned int, bigint> fiboMapCache = { {0, 0}, {1, 1} };

bigint fibonacci_map(unsigned int n) {
    if (auto cachedValue = fiboMapCache.find(n); cachedValue != fiboMapCache.end()) //C++17 syntax
        return std::get<1>(*cachedValue);


    auto lastItemsIter = fiboMapCache.end();
    lastItemsIter--;
    unsigned int startPoint = std::get<0>(*lastItemsIter);
    bigint a = std::get<1>(*lastItemsIter);
    lastItemsIter--;
    bigint b = std::get<1>(*lastItemsIter);

    for (unsigned int i = startPoint; i < n; ++i) {
        bigint c = a;
        a = a + b;
        b = c;
        fiboMapCache.insert({ i, b });
    }
    fiboMapCache.insert({ n, a });
    return a;
}


#include <unordered_map>
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, bigint> fiboUnorderedMapCache = { {0, 0}, {1, 1} };
unsigned int fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap = 1;

bigint fibonacci_unorderedMap(unsigned int n) {
    if (n < fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap)
        return fiboUnorderedMapCache[n];

    bigint a = fiboUnorderedMapCache[fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap],
           b = fiboUnorderedMapCache[fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap - 1];

    for (unsigned int i = fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap; i < n; ++i) {
        bigint c = a;
        a = a + b;
        b = c;
        fiboUnorderedMapCache.insert({ i, b });
    }
    fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap = n;
    fiboUnorderedMapCache.insert({ n, a });
    return a;
}

#include <array>
void matrix_power(std::array<bigint, 3>& result, std::array<bigint, 3>& M, unsigned int exp) {
    auto multiplyWith = [] (std::array<bigint, 3>&target, const std::array<bigint, 3>& with)
    {
        bigint a = target[0] * with[0] + target[1] * with[1],
               b = target[0] * with[1] + target[1] * with[2],
               c = target[1] * with[1] + target[2] * with[2];
        target[0] = std::move(a);
        target[1] = std::move(b);
        target[2] = std::move(c);
    };
    while (exp > 1) {
        if ((exp & 1) == 1)
            multiplyWith(result, M);
        multiplyWith(M, M);
        exp = exp >> 1;
    }
    multiplyWith(result, M);
}

std::pair<bigint,bigint> fibonacci_matrix(unsigned int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return std::make_pair(static_cast<int>(n), 0);

    //As an optimization, 2x2 symmetric matrices are stored as 3 numbers.
    std::array<bigint, 3> fiboMatrix    = { 1, 1, 0 },
                          result_matrix = { 1, 0, 1 };

    matrix_power(result_matrix, fiboMatrix, n - 1);
    return std::make_pair(result_matrix[0], result_matrix[1]);
}


#include <vector>
void fibonacci_range(std::vector<bigint>& result, unsigned int from, unsigned int to) {
    auto [a, b] = fibonacci_matrix(from);
    result.push_back(a);

    for (unsigned int i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        bigint c = a;
        a += b;
        bigint::_big_swap(b, c);
        result.push_back(std::move(a));
    }
}


#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    //{
    //    //Vanilla
    //    bigint fiboResults[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX] = { 0 };
    //    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    //    for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
    //        fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci(n);
    //    auto end = steady_clock::now();

    //    //for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n < MAXINDEX; ++n)
    //    //    std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
    //    std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
    //    std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;


    //    auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    //    std::cout << "fibonacci (vanilla, linear) : "
    //        << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    //}

    auto [f1, f2] = fibonacci_matrix(1 + MININDEX);

    {
        //Map
        bigint fiboResults[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX] = { 0 };

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        static_cast<void>(fibonacci_map(MAXINDEX));
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_map(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //    std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in map) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    fiboMapCache.clear();
    {
        //Map
        bigint fiboResults[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX] = { 0 };

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        fiboMapCache.insert({ 1 + MININDEX,f1 });
        fiboMapCache.insert({ MININDEX,f2 });
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_map(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //    std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in map, cache is initialized separately) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    {
        //Unordered map
        bigint fiboResults[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX] = { 0 };

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        static_cast<void>(fibonacci_unorderedMap(MAXINDEX));
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_unorderedMap(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //    std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in unordered map) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    fiboUnorderedMapCache.clear();
    fiboCalcUntil_unorderedMap = 1;
    {
        //Unordered map
        bigint fiboResults[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX] = { 0 };

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        fiboUnorderedMapCache.insert({ 1 + MININDEX,f1 });
        fiboUnorderedMapCache.insert({ MININDEX,f2 });
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_unorderedMap(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //    std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in unordered map, cache is initialized separately) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    {
        //Array
        bigint* fiboResults = new bigint[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX];

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        static_cast<void>(fibonacci_array(MAXINDEX));
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_array(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //    for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //        std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in array) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
        delete[] fiboResults;
    }
    fiboCalcUntil_array = 1;
    {
        //Array
        bigint* fiboResults = new bigint[1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX];

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        fiboArrayCache[1 + MININDEX] = f1;
        fiboArrayCache[MININDEX] = f2;
        for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
            fiboResults[n - MININDEX] = fibonacci_array(n);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //    for (unsigned int n = MININDEX; n <= MAXINDEX; ++n)
        //        std::cout << fiboResults[n - MININDEX] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (cached in array, cache is initialized separately) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
        delete[] fiboResults;
    }

    {
        //Hybrid
        std::vector<bigint> fiboResults;
        fiboResults.reserve(1 + MAXINDEX - MININDEX);

        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        fibonacci_range(fiboResults, MININDEX, MAXINDEX);
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        //for (auto fiboValue : fiboResults)
        //    std::cout << fiboValue << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << fiboResults[MAXINDEX - MININDEX] << std::endl;

        auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        std::cout << "fibonacci (hybrid matrix + vanilla) : "
            << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

---

The last point I want to mention is that adding code to manage a cache makes it more prone to bugs. I see the following 3 issues on another answer:

1. The below snippet looks in the map cache twice.

   ```cpp
   if (map.find(n) != map.end()) {
      return map[n];
   }
   ```

   It should instead do this to save half the time (C++17 and later syntax):

   ```cpp
   if (auto iter = map.find(n); iter != map.end())
       return std::get<1>(*iter);
   ```
2. Writing into the map at indices `n`,`n-1` and `n-2` causes many values to be written in the map thrice.
3. For the same reason as point 1, caling `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)` makes the function look up into the map twice when 1 time would suffice:

   ```cpp
   auto fib_2 = fib(n - 2);
   // At this point, the map is guaranteed to be filled up to n - 2.
   // If initialized with the first 2 items, i has at least 3 items in it.
   auto iter_to_fib_3 = std::advance(map.end(), -2); // worst case O(log(n)).
   auto fib_1 = fib_2 + std::get<1>(*iter_to_fib_3);
   ```

This is the risk when you add (unnecessary) code...

---

Side note:
You should consider measuring time in ms, as explained in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387757/20143744).

Comment: You are not memorizing at all. You will not reuse values from previous calls to the function. Also instead of using `long long` consider using `std::uint64_t`

Comment: That was his bug not his intent

Comment: memoization is also used not only for a single call, but also for multiple calls, like eg `fib(23)` can reuse the result from a previous `fib(12)`. And using a map for this kind of memoization is not "overkill"

Comment: "Complexity here is linear (O(n))" This is only for executing the function once, for executing it for n inputs it would be O(n^2).

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanations! will work it out on vscode, also the time complexity point also makes a lot of sense :) thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I am actually not satisfied by my answer anymore, editing it into a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact : If you want real speed/memoization you can memorize values at compile time using constexpr. Then at runtime getting the fibonacci number is just a lookup.

See compiler explorer : https://godbolt.org/z/daM8h83v1 and note the precompiled table `.L__const._Z20get_fibonacci_numberm.fibonacci_values:`

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto create_fibonacci_values()
{
    static_assert(N>2);
    std::array<std::uint64_t,N> values{1ul,1ul};
    for(std::size_t n{2ul}; n<N; ++n)
    {
        values[n] = (values[n-1] + values[n-2]);
    }

    return values;
}

constexpr auto get_fibonacci_number(std::size_t n)
{
    constexpr auto fibonacci_values = create_fibonacci_values<50>();
    assert((n>0) && (n <= fibonacci_values.size()));
    return fibonacci_values[n-1];
}

int main()
{
    for(std::size_t n = 1; n < 40; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << get_fibonacci_number(n) << "\n";
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe point out that it is `constexpr auto fibonacci_values = create_fibonacci_values<50>();` that triggers the compile time evaluation. Merely making the functions `constexpr` wouldnt be sufficient

Comment: seems interesting, had a look at constexpr over at (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-constexper-specifier-in-cpp/), thanks for the help and advice! :))

Comment: Dont use geek for geeks as reference it is low quality and often out of date

Answer (score 0):

In your `fibNum` function you're creating an empty map on each call and then doing a lookup in it. You need to *use* the map by looking up `n` in the map before resorting to the recursive calls `fibNum(n - 1)` and `fibNum(n - 2)` and you need to pass the map to the function as a *reference* parameter so the map can be built up and store the found numbers.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n, std::map<int, int>& map) {
    if (map.find(n) != map.end()) {
        return map[n];
    }

    int fib_1 = fib(n - 1, map);
    map[n - 1] = fib_1;
    int fib_2 = fib(n - 2, map);
    map[n - 2] = fib_2;
    int fib_n = fib_1 + fib_2;
    map[n] = fib_n;

    return fib_n;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> map = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        std::cout << fib(i, map) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification about the function causing more maps, it get it now!

Comment: Because the function takes a reference to a `std::map<int, int>` there's only _one_ map which gets updated on each loop.

Comment: You should remove `map[n-1] = fib_1` and `map[n-2]= fib_2`. The map is already filled for `n-1` and `n-2` using `fib_n` in the recursive calls (for `n-2`, it is even done with `fib_2` but also with the `fib_1` inside the call of `fib(n-1)`, i.e. 3 times in total). And if I follow yourcode correctly, you keep writing in the map 3 times instead of once for all the values between 2 and `n-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization in your solution doesn't work as your `std::map` is local which can be fixed by using a static or global map as has been advised in other answers. Time complexity of the solution will be `O(n)`.

If you really want an algorithmically faster solution, you can use [matrix exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form).

The idea here is that by visualising two consecutive numbers of fibonacci sequence as a `2 x 1` matrix and multiplying it by a square matrix, you can obtain the next sequence of fibonacci numbers.

[image]

By continuing this multiplication, you can obtain the `nth` number in the sequence.

Sample code for reference:

```
// Define a matrix multiplication function
vector<vector<long long>> multiply(
    const vector<vector<long long>>& A, const vector<vector<long long>>& B) {
    int n = A.size();
    vector<vector<long long>> C(n, vector<long long>(n, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return C;
}

// Define a function to calculate the matrix exponentiation
vector<vector<long long>> matrix_power(const vector<vector<long long>>& M, int exp) {
    int n = M.size();
    vector<vector<long long>> result(n, vector<long long>(n, 0));
    vector<vector<long long>> base = M;

    // Initialize the result matrix as the identity matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i][i] = 1;
    }

    while (exp > 0) {
        if (exp % 2 == 1) {
            result = multiply(result, base);
        }
        base = multiply(base, base);
        exp /= 2;
    }

    return result;
}

long long fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;

    // Define the base matrix
    vector<vector<long long>> base = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};

    // Calculate the (n-1)-th power of the base matrix
    vector<vector<long long>> result_matrix = matrix_power(base, n - 1);

    return result_matrix[0][0];
}
```

Time complexity of this solution: `O(k^3 log n)` where k is the order of the matrix. In this case, `k=2`.

Comment: That is an interesting solution but by far the slowest out of what I tested: 17secs for 50k loops on the 93 first fibonacci values when the next slowest solution I coded was 100ms. What do you think is the reason?

Comment: @Atmo The reason is the high cost of constants (matrix copies, k^3), in time complexity. Run this solution with n = 10^14 and observe the time difference. Don't limit yourself to `n=93` because of the 64 bit limit. Imagine you need to provide the last 2 digits of the answer (mod 100). The other solutions will run forever.

Answer (score -2):

This solves the Fibonacci problem using dynamic programming

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;     

int main() {
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int dp[n+1];//dp to store fibonachi number
  dp[0]=0;// base case 1
  dp[1]=1;//base case 2;
  // ith dp number will be at (i-1)th index in the dp array 
  for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)//time complexity O(n)
  {
    dp[i]=dp[i-1]+dp[i-2];
  }
  cout<<dp[n-1];
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: OP wants the solution using ecursion and memoization, not DP tables.

Comment: You should consider to run your answers through a compiler at least once before posting. You would have very clearly seen why this solution does not compile.

Comment: if you want this to be convrted to recursion form just copy my code ask chat gpt to convert the iterative dp to recursive although using iterative dp is much better to solve problem because of time complexity

Comment: @greybeard: had `dp` been declared/created with a `new int[]` operation, I could have understood. but `int dp[n+1]` with `n` being a variable won't work.

Comment: basically if you want to calculate the nth fibonaci number you have to know the prev n -1 fibonachi numbers so n  size dp is storing every fibonachi number till nth